# Upgrade to 5.47.2 failed on several systems - workaround?

Tags: extension, upgrade

In attempting to upgrade several 5.45.3 system to 5.47.2 I ran into this problem with 3 of them - "[info] $CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX_runNext_error = Exception: "API error: DB Error: constraint violation on ReportTemplate.create" This happened when the upgrade had almost completed, but left the database still thinking it was at 5.45.3.  This looks like a problem with the 'Extended Reports' extension - should this be reported as a bug against the extension? The upgrade from 5.45.3 to 5.46.3 works OK, by the way, this problem occurs on the upgrade to 5.47.2. So, I updated systems to 5.46.3 and am avoiding 5.47.2! -[image]  Trace back attached.

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully resolved still: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3101

Comment: Thanks, glad I reversed back into 5.46.3!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade civicrm extended report to 5.13 prior to CiviCRM 5.47.2

Comment: That might be enough in some situations but I think it's not fully resolved. Intermediate steps before 5.47 that need the managed entity to be there think it's not there because 5.13 only checks for the extension not the component, so in the intermediate step the extensions and managed entities thinks civigrant isn't installed. See lab ticket.

Comment: a) You would have to have to do that manually as that release is not offered in the extensions before 5.47 and b) you would have to know about it!  A pity that 5.47 was released with a known problem so hope that people see this first